# Better way to include dynamic object in template

Tags: flask, jinja2

i've made a dashboard with dynamic module with all the same structure/graphics but with different content and organization.

I've tried to find how can i reuse part of my code in the blueprint flask method but with no success.

The method that i found is this:

**WidgetGeneric.py:**

```
from flask import render_template
from flask.views import View


class WidgetGeneric(View):
title = "default_title"
has_dropdown = False

def render_template(self, context):


    return render_template(self.get_template_name(),
                           title=context.get("title", self.title),
                           has_dropdown=context.get("has_dropdown", self.has_dropdown)
   )

def get_template_name(self):
    raise NotImplementedError()

def dispatch_request(self):
    context = {'objects': self.get_objects()}
    return self.render_template(context)
```

**Widget1.py**

```
from .WidgetGeneric import WidgetGeneric


class Widget1(WidgetGeneric):

def get_template_name(self):
    return 'helper/widget/widget1.html'
```

**index_controller.py**

```
from .helper.widget.Widget1 import Widget1

def index():

widgets = []

widgets.append(Widget1().render_template({'title' : "pippo", "has_dropdown": True}))
widgets.append(Widget1().render_template({'title' : "pluto"}))
widgets.append(Widget1().render_template({}))


return render_template('index/index.html', logged=True, widget1_render=widgets)
```

Widget1.html extends WidgetGeneric.html

Widget1 is included in **index.html** as follow:

```
{% for widget in widget1_render %}
    {{ widget|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

There is another way to get the same in a more correct form without using "macro" or "include" because i need, for every widget, querying different db tables or implement different customization?